# How to fill space with color between two different layers?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I draw a simple snake for my game and I created it with brush tool. Now I want to fill this drawing between lines that are on different layers, image that I want to paint this drawning as a normal kid. Closed lines I want to paint with different colors. My problem is that I don't know how to use properly live paint bucket. When I want to paint something i have `not allowed` button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use *Live Paint Bucket* tool and maintain your original layers.

You need to convert your artwork (or a copy of it) to a *Live paint Group* before being able to use the *Live Paint Bucket* tool.

This can be done by selecting your artwork and choosing *Object > Live Paint > Make*.

After you've done that, it's not possible to revert the artwork back to it's initial state. It's a bit like flattening a pixel based image.

Read more about this in the [manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/live-paint-groups.html).